# Failed to execute SSIS package in SQL Server 2012 and Windows Server 2012 without recompiling

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ssis, sql-server-2012, windows-server-2012

I have created an integration package in VS 2012 and Windows 7.

I use Script Component as Source in Data Flow with one output column. The column's name contains Umlaut (Column_ü).

The package works fine in VS 2012 but The package doesn't work in SQL Server 2012 and Windows Server 2012 after deployment.

I get the following error:

> Error at Data Flow Task [Script Component [9]]: The component metedata is out of sync with the compiled script. Recompile the script using the Script Component Editor.
>   Error at Data Flow Task [SSIS.Pipeline]: "Script Component" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".
>   Error at Data Flow Task [SSIS.Pipeline]: One or more component failed validation.

If I open project in VS 2012 and Windows Server 2012 I get the same error but I can recompile the script component using the Script Component Editor in Visual Studio.

If I use column without Umlaut The package work in Windows 7 and Windows Server 2012 without recompiling.

Please help to resolve this issue

Comment: Fixed title - there's no SQL Server **2012 R2** release (yet) - assuming you mean just **2012**

Comment: I would ... umm ... use the column name without Umlaut.  SSIS is fussy in this area.